# How to guarantee sending message using class chain in sequence in multi-threading scenario

Tags: java, multithreading

I used a chain A-B-C to send `Message` of PAUSE and PLAY. I want to guarantee `Class C` to send message PAUSE followed by PLAY in sequence. 
(I expect C to send PAUSE-PLAY, but sometimes it became PLAY-PAUSE).

Currently, I added 1 second sleep at each sendMessage in `A`. But I think it is not thread safe.

So what is the best way to achieve this in-sequence goal?

```
   [testng] B sending event PAUSE 7951016310326825
   [testng] B sending event PLAY 7951016310683642
   [testng] C sending event PLAY 7951016311536353
   [testng] C sending event PAUSE 7951016311575708

public Class A {
    Private B b;
    @Override
    public void processCommand(Message)
    throws Exception {
    onPause(Message);
    onPlay(Message);
    }

    private void onPause(Message) {
        b.process(Message);
    }

    private void onPlay(Message) {
        b.process(Message);
    }
}


public Class B implements Runnable {
    private C c;
    protected Boolean isRunning = true;
    protected Thread runThread;

    public void process(Message) {
        System.out.println("B Sending message " + Message.id);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
    }

    public void startup()
    throws Exception
    {
        this.runThread = new Thread(this, this.subsystemId);
        this.isRunning = true;
        this.runThread.start();
    }
}

public Class C {
    public void process(Message) {
        System.out.println("C Sending message " + Message.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there is nothing about multi-threading. All run in sequence. If you see output not in sequence it is not about how messages processed actually.

Just add timestamp to your output and you will see it. like:

```
System.out.println("Sending message " + Message.id + " at " + System.nanoTime());
```

BTW: if you simplified code too much and B actually uses separate threads for each message in parallel, there is nothing you can do from Sender point. All must be designed differently perhaps with queue and one (and only one) instance of B as a listener.

UPD: about Multi-threading in B example:

```
    public void process(Message message) {

    Thread processingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {           
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ... do something ...
            ... call other objects/methods etc...
            System.out.println("Sending message " + message.id);

        }
    });

    processingThread.start();

}
```

In general such code does not guarantee that all messages be processed in sequence. It depends how many other objects and methods calls are in `run()` method. 
Another thread can get execution control between methods calls in current Thread.

Comment: Thanks Vadim. Would you please provide a bit detail regarding your queue suggestion? I used Thread.sleep() and it worked. Would you please also comment if it is a working way to solve your mentioned "B actually used separate threads for each message in parallel"?

Comment: As I said. If your code looks exactly as you showed there is no multi-threading at all. And if you see Output in different order it is just because `System.out.println` uses another thread(s) internally and does not guarantee that messages will be printed in the same order when they send in too close time. That why I suggested to add timestamp in nanoseconds. For such short code it may be visible that process sequence is 1/2/3 even when `System.out.println` printed them in different order. When you added sleep you just allowed System.out.println to complete its work before next message

Comment: Got you Vadim. I just removed multi-threading tag and edited my title to reflect the correct question.

Comment: About Queue it is a big topic. You can dig through Java documentation starting from `java.util.Queue` interface. Main Idea is - Class A pushes message into queue (in FIFO mode), while `Class B` polls top message from queue in infinite loop and when it has one it processes it, then tries to poll next message and so on.

Comment: I have one more question in queue model. Where should i place this FIFO queue? I am thinking to put it in `Class B`. But might this cause out-of-sequence, as I need to change  `public void process(Message)` to add `Message` into queue?

Comment: HEY @Vadim, I updated my question with more detail, and let me know if you have any insights to solve my issue by using your queue model.